# Determine weights for a risk weighted calculation for road safety

Tags: weights, risk, relative-risk

I'm looking to quantify route safety for each route in our route database. For this, I have the following data in the past 2 years:

- accidents observed for each route,
- no. of phone usage events
- no. of high acceleration events
- no. of braking events
- no. of potential collision events

At first I wanted to add up these features, but we know that accidents should have higher influence on route safety calculation than # of phone usage events. Perhaps potential collision events should be weighted higher than # of braking events. Finally accidents are generally less common than phone events and without the appropriate weights the final road safety metric would be influenced more by phone events than crashes, which is absurd.
I'm not sure how to decide on the weights without making them up.

Is there a systematic approach to determining the weights of each feature? Let me know if you have any questions. TIA.

Jimmy